# Mozilla DeepSpeech: How to generate a SRT file from multiple segmented audio file?

Tags: python, caption, subtitle, mozilla-deepspeech

I've been following this [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/generating-subtitles-automatically-using-mozilla-deepspeech-562c633936a7) on generating an SRT subtitle file from video/audio files using **Mozilla DeepSpeech**.

I've been able to remove the silent portion of the audio **.wav** file into multiple segmented **.wav** files based on the guide using **pyAudioAnalysis** library.

[Segmented audio files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvQX4.png)

However, I'm currently having difficulty understanding how to read through the multiple-segmented files and generate a subtitle **.srt** file using **Mozilla DeepSpeech**. I've attached an image of the segmented audio file above.

As for my current code, most are similar to the guide I'm following but it doesn't explain well enough regarding the functions.

**SilenceRemoval Function**

```
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioBasicIO as aIO
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioSegmentation as aS

def silenceRemoval(input_file, smoothing_window = 1.0, weight = 0.2):
    print("Running silenceRemoval function\n")
    [fs, x] = aIO.read_audio_file(input_file)
    segmentLimits = aS.silence_removal(x, fs, 0.05, 0.05, smoothing_window, weight)
    
    for i, s in enumerate(segmentLimits):
        strOut = "{0:s}_{1:.3f}-{2:.3f}.wav".format(input_file[0:-4], s[0], s[1])
        # wavfile.write(strOut, fs, x[int(fs * s[0]):int(fs * s[1])])
        write_file("audio", strOut, ".wav", x[int(fs * s[0]):int(fs * s[1])], fs)
    
    print("\nsilenceRemoval function completed")
```

**Writing .wav file into multiple segments**

```
import os
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile

def write_file(output_file_path, input_file_name, name_attribute, sig, fs):
    """
    Read wave file as mono.

    Args:
        - output_file_path (str) : path to save resulting wave file to.
        - input_file_name  (str) : name of processed wave file,
        - name_attribute   (str) : attribute to add to output file name.
        - sig            (array) : signal/audio array.
        - fs               (int) : sampling rate.

    Returns:
        tuple of sampling rate and audio data.
    """
    # set-up the output file name
    fname = os.path.basename(input_file_name).split(".wav")[0] + name_attribute
    fpath = os.path.join(output_file_path, fname)
    wavfile.write(filename=fpath, rate=fs, data=sig)
    print("Writing data to " + fpath + ".")
```

**main() calling the functions**

```
video_name = "Videos\MIB_Sample.mp4"
audio_name = video_name + ".wav"

# DeepSpeech Model and Scorer
ds = Model("deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm")
scorer = ds.enableExternalScorer("deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer")

def main():     
    # Extract audio from input video file
    extractAudio(video_name, audio_name)

    print("Splitting on silent parts in audio file")
    silenceRemoval(audio_name)

    generateSRT(audio_name)
```

**generateSRT() function**

```
def generateSRT(audio_file_name):
    command = ["deepspeech", "--model", ds, 
                "--scorer", scorer,
                "--audio", audio_file_name]
    try:
        ret = sp.call(command, shell=True)
        print("generating subtitles")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", str(e))
        exit(1)
```

I'm currently trying to generate subtitle from the single extracted audio file but I'm facing this error

> Error:  expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Model

Appreciate any help on how to loop through the folder that contains the segmented audio file to be read and generate into an SRT file using **Mozilla DeepSpeech** and output it to another folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to address the specific error you are encountering here; the blog post that you linked to is a good guide for the end to end process of creating `.srt` files using DeepSpeech.

In your code here:

```
command = ["deepspeech", "--model", ds, 
                "--scorer", scorer,
                "--audio", audio_file_name]
```

you are invoking the `deepspeech` binary from the command line, and passing the model as an argument, using the variable `ds`. If you invoke `deepspeech` from the command line, it expects a *file path* to where the model file (the `.pbmm` file) is.

This is why you are receiving the error:

```
Error: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Model
```

because the `deepspeech` binary is expecting a *file path*, not a *model object*. Try replacing `ds` with the *file path* to the model file, rather than making `ds` a Model.

For more information on how to call `deepspeech` from the command line, see [this page in the documentation](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/USING.html#py-usage).